# How to pass GET response data to POST Request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new using Angularjs and I am having an issue while parsing a JSON response. I am doing client side authentication for the **login page** and I have used `get` request to fetch data from servers side and `post` request for client side. 
HTML code :

```
    <form ng-submit="loginform(logcred)" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid center" name="logform"><br/><br>
<tr ng-repeat="logcred in serverinfo"></tr>
<div>
  <label form="emailinput"><b>Email</b></label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="uname" id="emailinput" placeholder="you@example.com" ng-model="logcred.username" >
</div>

<div>
  <label form="pwdinput"><b>Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="pwdinput" placeholder="*******" ng-model="logcred.password">
</div>

<div>
    <button type="cancel" class="btn" ng-click="toggle_cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
</div>
<br/>   
</form>
```

AngularJS code :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
  myApp.controller('credientials', function($scope, $http) {
            /* server side response*/
  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/loginfo
  .then(
  function successCallback(response){
  $scope.serverinfo = response.data;
  });       

/* client-side response*/

$scope.loginform = function(serverinfo,username,password){
  $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/loginfo',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            "username" :username,
            "password" :password,
            }
        })
        .then(
        function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response);
        if (serverinfo.username === response.data.username && serverinfo.password === response.data.password) { 
        $scope.signinfo = response.data;
        }else{
            console.log("Error: " + response)
        }
    });
}
```

Problem what I am facing is, I need to send the `GET` response data into `POST` request and there I am doing the condition check, if the username and password matches, it's should give success meassage. But I am not sure my thinking is right or not.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in server side you check username and password , if match send success message , you dont need send get request to do it

Comment: @ThanhTùng. I created plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/G1ld4uMcJ1nWCYNZquuM?p=info

Comment: I am not getting how to do the server side check, could you modify my plunker or else  if you have any working example drop me @ThanhTùng

Comment: Why you need get request to get user name and password  ? You dont need it , just post data in server , check in database , if match , send success message to user

Comment: actually I have not used data-base . I have used `JSON` server. That's why I am thinking

Comment: If you have data in get request . Just check ng-model of username and password input with data when user click login

Comment: Or if you want make get request in post check this https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/453

Comment: yeah sure.. @ThanhTùng

Comment: @ThanhTùng. Just now i went through the post which use have posted. But i din't got any proper information. Because they have said , it's an out off the box question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156526/discussion-between-srk-and-thanh-tung).

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
$scope.loginform = function(serverinfo,username,password){
  $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/loginfo',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            "username" :username,
            "password" :password,
            }
        })
        .then(
        function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response);
        if (response) {  // Response will be either true or false. For this yu need to change the API response.
            //Logged in successfully
        }else{
           //Something went wrong
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: yeah. I'll try it @rakesh